# The type or namespace name 'Testing' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-cli

I pulled the latest code from https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev

Modified the code to add few imports

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing.xunit;
```

And I built the application for dotnet cli

Command used

```
    c:\...\...\Musicstore>dotnet.exe restore
    c:\...\...\Musicstore>dotnet.exe build
```

I get the below error 
The type or namespace name 'Testing' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The same code base worked initially , however it fails to build now
Is there any changes made to this package ?

Answer (score 0):

you mean?

> dnu restore
>
> dnu build

(https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility)

Comment: MSFT has moved from dnvn , dnx    to   command line... http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

For those who will come here with the same problem:
Just add another source to your nuget settings
https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json
then install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing via nuget as usual

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the following worked for me:
1.) Build -> Clean solution
2.) Build -> Rebuild solution
3.) Exit
4.) Open VS

Hope it helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).